# Ansible mount and variables

Tags: ansible, mount

```
ansible --version
ansible 2.3.1.0
```

from playbook

```
- name:  add mount point1 to /etc/fstab
  mount: path="{{base_dir}}"/"{{mpoint1}}" src="{{dev}}"/"{{vg_name}}"/"{{lv_name1}}" fstype=xfs opts=defaults state=present
```

`/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev"/"vg_gluster"/"brick1 /bricks"/"brick1 xfs defaults 0 0
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 1):

What you're asking is not clear. Please edit your question to be more precise.

I guess you're asking why `"` are written to `/etc/fstab`

The answer is that you have too much double-quotes in your task.

Try this:

```
- name:  add mount point1 to /etc/fstab
  mount: path="{{base_dir}}/{{mpoint1}}" src="{{dev}}/{{vg_name}}/{{lv_name1}}" fstype=xfs opts=defaults state=present
```

Or even better:

```
- name:  add mount point1 to /etc/fstab
  mount:
    path: "{{ base_dir }}/{{ mpoint1 }}"
    src: "{{ dev }}/{{ vg_name }}/{{ lv_name1 }}"
    fstype: xfs
    opts: defaults
    state: present
```